# How to get data displayed from one table from database -Drupal

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

I am creating a table view for my custom module that displays user some custom data that he created.

Example table hour:

```
hour_id    hour
  1       07:00
  2       07:30
  3       08:00
  4       08:30
```

Example table data:

```
user_id    user   hour_start    hour_end
  1        name     1              3
  2        name     1              2
```

Note: I save ID from table hour to table data. User has a dropdown menu for start and end.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT ho.hour,h.hour FROM {data} t
                    INNER JOIN {hour} ho ON t.hour_start=ho.hour_id
                    INNER JOIN {hour} h ON t.hour_end=h.hour_id
                    WHERE t.made=:t",array(":t"=>$temp_user));


    $rows = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
    $rows[] = array ('data' => 
    array(
        $row -> hour, // putting ho.hour gives error
        $row -> hour, // putting h.hour gives error
        ),
    );
```

My problem is that i get in the table only one hour. How can i get for row one 
07:00(1) for one column and 08:00(3) without creating a separate tables for hour_start and hour_end .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using column aliases. Change the query to:

```
SELECT ho.hour ho_hour, h.hour h_hour FROM {data} t ...
```

and then get the data using:

```
$row -> ho_hour,
$row -> h_hour,
```